# Listener or Notification on "Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock"

Tags: android, android-activity

In one of my test devices, I am receiving this dreaded warning in LogCat:

```
07-20 09:57:02.093: W/ActivityManager(1159): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
07-20 09:57:02.218: W/ActivityManager(1159): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{4072b5e8 com.rero.myapp/.MyActivity}
```

My initial research revealed that this is a common eyebrow-raiser:

1. "The app could have [exceeded the VM budget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6028975) and ran out of memory."
2. "This [can be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10069805)."
3. [Network problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9870499)?
4. Activity is [taking to long to start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7490208) (too much processing on UI thread?)
5. Services & Broadcasts involving [HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3520254/576267).
6. And on and on[...](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Launch%20timeout%20has%20expired,%20giving%20up%20wake%20lock!)

My questions are:

1. What are the implications of "Launch timeout has expired"? What does the system do? (e.g. one source claims it kills my application, but I actually see my application proceeding normally after a 1-2 minutes of perceived freezing)
2. Is there **a way to get notified in my application** about this warning?

Comment: I've had this happen when I created an unintentional infinite layout pass loop. Do you have any layout or draw (OnGlobalLayout, OnPreDraw, etc.) listeners in the Activity that you are navigating *away* from?

Comment: @kcoppock Actually I don't have any of those you mentioned, but I do attempt to `HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()` for http://www.google.com and... it times out after **6 minutes and 36 seconds!** The Launch timeout occurs much earlier and so I am hoping to use it as a helper to handle this unusual situation.

Comment: Can you post how you're attempting the connection? I would definitely make sure it's on a separate thread (use an AsyncTask).

Comment: @kcoppock The HTTP timeout mystery is a different subject and I just posted [a question dedicated to it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11582390/576267). I am still interested in a way to get **notified** in my application about **Launch** timeout warnings.

Comment: I upvoted your other question. I'm not sure why that's happening, but I do think the two are probably related somehow. I'm not sure there is a way to get notified about a logged warning other than just seeing it in the logs.

Comment: @kcoppock Thanks. I just checked and discovered that I *am* doing the HTTP on the main thread (aka UI thread). I never used AsyncTask before so a pointer to how to use it in most correct manner for HTTP would be appreciated. +1 x 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the general *idea* of what I would try, but how you handle the AsyncTask depends on what you're doing after you get the status. I would do something like this:

```
private class GetHttpStatus extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String[] params) {
        private boolean status;

        //this will be the string you pass in execute()
        String urlString = params[0];

        HttpURLConnection httpConnection;
        try {
            URL gurl = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection connection = gurl.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);
            httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                status = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status = false;
        } finally { 
            if(httpConnection != null) httpConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        //Here you'll do whatever you need to do once the connection
        //status has been established
        MyActivity.notifyHttpStatus(result);
    }
}

//in your Activity somewhere, you would call...

new GetHttpStatus.execute("http://www.amazon.com");
```

Comment: Thanks +1. If no one comes up with a notification or listener to the Launch warning I will accept as well.