# HttpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout is not working

Tags: android, timeout, connect

I have an Android app that connects in a server searching for updates.
If the server takes a long time to respond (+500ms), I have to finish my method and  continue with the program.

I already set the `readTimeout` and `connectTimeout` to **500 ms**, but even then my method are taking about 30 seconds in this line: **`c.connect();`**

This is my code:

```
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) updateUrl.openConnection();
c.setConnectTimeout(500);
c.setReadTimeout(500);
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
c.setDoOutput(true);
c.connect();  // the program stops here
```

What I need to do?

Comment: Check out [this related question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11583328/1134705)

Comment: Thaks for the answer, Asok, But I am trying to connect in a local server. The server IP is 192.168.16.150. The URL connect has this value: `http://192.168.16.150/service/android/update/myUpdate.apk`.

Comment: This problem occurs only in some smartphones. I think this occurs only in Android 2.3. In android 2.2 and 4.0 everthing is normal. I'm not using AsyncTask because I need connect for only 500 ms, and I did not think necessary.

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment, sorry, anyway I asked what API level you're on because `HttpURLConnection` "has more bugs" on Eclair (5-7) and Froyo (8)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Asok!! I solved using org.apache.http.client.HttpClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot, Asok!! I solved using org.apache.http.client.HttpClient:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 500);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 500);

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(updateUrl.toURI());
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpClient.setParams(httpParameters);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();

//download file.....
```

Comment: +1 Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner. I was going to suggest `HttpClient`. I would suggest doing a API check, if device is pre-8 then use `HttpClient` else `HttpURLConnection`, Google has come out and said that they are going to support `HttpURLConnection` for future versions.

Comment: In gingerbread

HttpURLConnnection takes double time as set in  setConnectTimeout()
i.e. if I set time to 30 secs it time out after 1 min, if I set time as 1 min it time outs after 2 minutes. Does any work around exists for that ?